# How to calculate the derivative of the solution of ParametricNDSolveValue?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

Consider the following code:

```
Sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{e1'[t] == s e2[t], e2'[t] == -s e1[t],e1[0] == 1, e2[0] == 0}, {e1, e2}, {t, 0, 1}, s]
fun[t_, s_] := Through[Sol[s][t]][[1]];
Plot[fun[t, 1], {t, 0, 10}]
dfun[t_, s_] = Derivative[1, 0][fun][t, s]
Plot[dfun[t, 10], {t, 0, 1}]
```

The aim is to find and plot the derivative in `t` of `fun`, but I get the output:

```
s'[t]
```

and a line along the x axis as  a plot, which is the wrong solution.

How do I find the derivative of the solution of `ParametricNDSolveValue`?

**EDIT** To be clear: I need to keep `s` as a parameter, I know that if I write `dfun[t_] = D[Through[Sol[1][t]][[1]], t]` I can plot the deirvative, but I do not want to fix the value of `s`

Comment: Inspect the sub expressions: `Through[Sol[s][t]]` is different from `Through[Sol[1][t]]`, so `fun[t, s]` behaves differently when `s` is a symbol and when it’s numeric.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I see the problem, but how do I solve it? The real aim is to use this derivative inside another `ParametricNDSolveValue`

Comment: You could use `s_?NumericQ` in the definition of `fun`, so that `Sol[s]` would evaluate to a list before part 1 is taken.  Or you could use `Indexed[…, 1]` instead of `…[[1]]`. You could also add `e1’` to the list of expressions to return `{e1, e2, e1’}` and take part 3 with NumericQ or Indexed as mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can include derivative in solution as follows

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{e1'[t] == s e2[t], e2'[t] == -s e1[t], 
   e1[0] == 1, e2[0] == 0}, {e1, e2, e1', e2'}, {t, 0, 1}, s]
fun[t_, s_] := Through[sol[s][t]][[1]];
Plot[fun[t, 1], {t, 0, 10}]

dfun[t_, s_] := Through[sol[s][t]][[3]];
Plot[dfun[t, 10], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Figure 1]